# Is is possible to re-export to CSV from a GAE bulkloader.py sqlite database?

Tags: google-app-engine, bulkloader

I ran bulkloader with parameters to export my bigtable to a csv file, and it spent a lot of time downloading the table (it's large).  It failed to export do to a problem with one of the lambda expressions in the Exporter class.  I fixed that, can I run bulkloader.py again without having to redownload all of the data from GAE?  I'd like to point it back at the .sql file it downloads and just tell it to export again to CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you use the same progress database, it may pick up from where it left off, though.